# How to prevent internal field shift in views when base table gets additional fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

Today there was an interesting issue in our MS SQL Server database view.

There are several base tables. One is sys_user an the others join in some additional data.

The (beginning of) SQL view definition looks like this:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[V_Usage] AS
SELECT u.*,
    case when assexcl.sys_id IS NULL THEN asslookup.home_office ELSE assexcl.home_office END [Home Office],
    case when assexcl.sys_id IS NULL THEN asslookup.assigned_group ELSE assexcl.assigned_group END [Assigned Group],
    case when assexcl.sys_id IS NULL THEN asslookup.drs_hub ELSE assexcl.drs_hub END [DRS Hub],
  x.request_sys_id, x.request_pa_name, x.u_allocation request_allocation, x.u_negotiated_deadline, x.u_research_time, x.u_qa_time_drs, x.u_assignment_group, x.u_utilization_category
FROM sys_user u
    LEFT outer join (...
```

The select u.* brings in all fields of the sys_user table and some other fields are also shown per user which is queried in the lower part.

After adding a field in the sys_user table we had the issues that all content in the last fields was shiftet one column to the right.

[Home Office] did contain the last field of the sys_user table, 
[Assigned Group] did contain the content of [Home Office]
etc.

First I would like to understand the issue. I think it is due to internal compilation and referencing.

And second I would like to have a solution to make that not happen again. I would prefer not reference all fields directly in the view since it was intentional that all sys_user fields should be in the view.

Is there a kind of flag or db hint to keep those view correct even when base tables get fields added?

Any information appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no other solution other than explicitly listing the column names in your view in the order you want them returned. Although you should definitely be doing this anyway - [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). If someone adds a column to `sys_users` they will also need to remember to modify the view if the new column is also required in the view.

Comment: With regard to your issue of seeing data in the wrong column, where did you observe this? In SSMS, or in an application? If it is the latter, I expect that you are reading the data using column ordinals rather than column names, therefore after the view updated, the application layer was out of date, and reading the wrong column.

Comment: Can't agree more. Replace the `SELECT *`, solve the problem. `*` is "fine" when you're using ad hoc SQL, however, if you're ever writing SQL for an object, **always** declare your columns; otherwise using `*` will likely result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: If the `VIEW`'s definition wasn't updated though, @GarethD , then that wouldn't happen. Note that the new column is missing from the `VIEW` in this  [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=613104d0b7f02cc5eab9a13538abc247). We appear to not have the complete story here.

Comment: Thanks for the informative input. Unfortunately it is the whole story. View definition did not change. Just the sys_user table. The error was in SSMS also. Doing a "Script View" -> "as ALTER to" and re-running the DDL solved it. I will replace the * be the complete field list now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent lots and lots of time (once upon a time) debugging problems cause by such queries, I strongly advise you to never use `*` in views.

That said, you can prevent changes to the underlying tables using [`SCHEMABINDING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition.

As the documentation says, this prevents changes to the other tables *unless the view is recreated*.  It does not automatically change the view, but it does prevent damaging changes from occurring.

You might also investigate WHY table structures are changing in -- what is presumably -- a production database.  That seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont' use `u.*`. This is generally not a good practice, and the issue that you are having now is one of the reason why.

While selecting `*`, there is no "automagical" solution that would allow you to *keep those view correct even when base tables get fields added*.

Instead, you should enumerate all the columns that you want to pick from `sys_user` in the `select` clause. This way, you do control which columns are being displayed in the view, and in which order the appear.

When new columns are added, you can modifiy the definition of the view to add them in the position that you like.